# How do I load data from CSV file into a numpy array

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, dataset

I want to practice machine learning so I went to kaggle to get any dataset.
But I don't know how to create numpy array from the csv file data.
[Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data)

If anyone can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using pandas DataFrames for these kind of tasks.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
```

If you still wish to use an array, you can always:

```
df.values
```